# Can't connect java client to Marklogic database

Tags: connection, marklogic

I've just installed a MarkLogic nosql database out of the box on a windows machine.
 I wrote a simple javaclient to put data in to the database but I get this error:

```
 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://my.caci.local:8003 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
```

The Marklogic database is started.   This is the code :

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8003, "admin", "admin", Authentication.DIGEST);

   XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();    BinaryDocumentManager binMgr = client.newBinaryDocumentManager();

   DOMHandle handle = new DOMHandle();    for (int i = 0; i < AANT_PERSONEN; i++)    {
      Document document = createDocument(i);
      String docId = "/zaak/" + 20;
      handle.set(document);
      docMgr.write(docId, handle);    }
```

....

The Marklogic console reports the following ports to be active on my.caci.local:

```
Default :: Admin : 8001 [HTTP]
Default :: App-Services : 8000 [HTTP]
Default :: HealthCheck : 7997 [HTTP]
Default :: Manage : 8002 [HTTP]
```

I'm new to marklogic and this is my question:
   - what port should I use to connect to from my java client?

Comment: I believe the Java API is built on the REST API of ML. Did you create a REST API instance with your database?

Answer (score 3):

In agreement with MystyxMac, I notice the console does not report a REST server on 8003.

Here's the documentation for setting up a REST server:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_97899

You should also add users for the rest-reader, rest-writer, and rest-admin roles.

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you can simply switch the port you are using to 8000.

From the documentation:

> When you install MarkLogic Server, a pre-configured REST API instance
>   is available on port 8000. This instance uses the Documents database
>   as the content database and the Modules database as the modules
>   database.
>
> The instance on port 8000 is convenient for getting started, but you
>   will usually create a dedicated instance for production purposes.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_15309